# Kinect v2 SDK Clothes Detection

Tags: c#, opencv, object, detection, kinect-sdk

So, recently I managed to land myself a Kinect v2 project (hurray!) on my Industrial Placement which is supposed to detect if a person is wearing the correct PPE or (personal protective equipment to you and me).

Included in this scope is detecting if the person is wearing the correct:

- Hazard Protection Suit
- Boots
- Gloves
- Hat
- A beard mesh! (Only if they have a beard)

I have only recently begun working with the Kinect v2 Sensor so you will have to forgive any ignorance on my part. I am new to this whole game but have worked through a fair few examples online. I guess I am just looking for advice/sources on how best to solve the problem.

Sources online seem scarce for trying to detect if a person is WEARING something. There are a couple of parts to this project:

- Split up human into components (hands, feet, head, body) while retaining colour. This part I imagine would be best done by the Kinect SDK.
- Give a percentage likelihood that the person's hand part is wearing gloves, head part is wearing hat etc... I've seen some ideas for this including graphics packages such as OpenCV.

I'm looking for advice concerning both parts of this project. Feel free to ignore the waffling below, but I thought it best to post some of my own ideas first.

Idea (and worked example) 1 - Point clouds

I have done some preliminary projects involving basic detection of humans. In fact, grabbing the VS project from this source: http://laht.info/record-3d-video-with-kinect-v2-and-play-it-back-in-the-browser/ I have managed to create a .ply file out of human beings. The problem here would be trying to split the .ply 3D image up to identify the suit, hat, gloves, boots (and I guess) beard. I imagine this is a fairly complex task.

Of the 3 ideas however, I'm coming back around to this one. Splitting up a 3D .ply image and trying to detect the PPE could turn out to be more accurate. Would need advice here.

Idea 2 - Blob Detection

Using this: http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/kinect/Kinect--OpenCV--WPF--Blob-Tracking I pondered whether there would be a good way of splitting up a human into a colour picture of their "hand part", "head part", "body part" etc with the Kinect v2 SDK. Maybe I could then use a graphics package like OpenCV to test if the colours are similar or if the logo on the suit can be detected. Unfortunately, there is no logo currently on the gloves and boots so this might not turn out to give a very reliable result.

Idea 3 - Change the PPE

This isn't ideal but if I can't do this another way, I could perhaps insist that logos would need to be put on the gloves and suit. In this worst case scenario, I guess I would be trying to just detect some text in 3D space.

Summary

I'd be grateful for any advice on how to begin tackling this problem. Even initial thoughts might spark something :)

Peace!

Benjamin Biggs